# How to concatenate two variables in a controller class and pass it to all views of the class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I'm trying to concatenate two class spesific variables in controller and pass it to all views without repeating the same variable in every controller methods.

Example code:

```
    class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    private $global_path; //Comes from .env
    private $sub_folder = '/products_folder';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Frontend Image Path - to pass into all views
        $frontend_path = $this->global_path.$this->sub_folder;

    }
}
```

I want to pass '$frontend_path' to all blade views created in the controller without repeating it in every single method like

```
return view('example_view', compact('frontend_path');
```

I tried View::share... but couldn't do it.

**The '$sub_folder' variable doesn't have the same value in all controllers.**

Is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: If it is independent of your controller and model, why you are not making a helper or constant file to store all these stuffs and just use that from there?

Comment: No, like i said '$sub_folder' variable is different in every controller. If it was the case i can easily define it in .env and call it from there.

Comment: Is there respective controller for respective model, then you may consider defining static methods and call them from controllers.

Comment: Is the `sub_folder` path related to the controller name?

Comment: @RossWilson no it is not.

Comment: @megavolkan Are you getting any error for my answers, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, I think you can change it to

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
   public $frontend_path;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->frontend_path = env('GLOBAL_PATH') . '/products_folder';
   }

   public function index()
   {
       $x = $this->frontend_path;
       return view('index', compact('x'));
   }
```

}

and directly use it like `$this->frontend_path` or like below `SELF::$frontend_path`

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public static $frontend_path;

    public function __construct() {
        SELF::$frontend_path = env('GLOBAL_PATH') . '/products_folder';
    }

     public function index()
     {
         $x = SELF::$frontend_path;
         return view('index', compact('x'));
     }
}
```

or

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public static $frontend_path;

    public function __construct() {
        SELF::$frontend_path = env('GLOBAL_PATH') . '/products_folder';
        view()->share('frontend_path', SELF::$frontend_path);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

in view

```
{{ $frontend_path }}
```

Comment: @megavolkan are you getting any error for this? please let me know.

Comment: Yes, error is: 'Constant expression contains invalid operations'

Comment: @megavolkan now can you try it and let me know the result?

Comment: @megavolkan I just tried in my installation and It is working fine for me, can you please try and let me now?

Comment: but how can i pass this to my blade views without repeating it in all the Controller methods

Comment: this is what i'm trying to avoid from the beginnig. I don't want to pass this variable to every single view in the controller. I need to define it once in the controller and share it to views used in the Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190170/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-megavolkan).

Comment: @megavolkan now try the 3rd one, I have added and let me know, what you think about it?

Comment: Tried third one but returns 'undefined variable' error. Somehow view()->share() function (or View::share facade) doesn't work (I use Laravel 5.7)

Comment: @megavolkan I tested with laravel 5.6.39 and it is working fine for me, let me try with 5.7 and 5.8

Comment: @megavolkan checck [this](https://github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/spatidemo/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php)